# In Datascript, how can I create a new attribute from the value of another?

Tags: clojurescript, datalog, datascript

Trying to create a new attribute where the value is the result of a transformation on a different attribute for the same entity. So, say I have a database where every entity has attribute `:content`. I want to have an additional attribute for every entity called `:transformed` whose value is the result of applying function `f` to `:content`. How would I go about this idiomatically and efficiently? Currently trying to do this by performing a transaction and assigning the value of the new attribute to the value of the function applied to a query for the value of the original attribute for that entity.

If it's not obvious, I'm fairly new to Datalog and Datascript

```clj
(doseq [included-block-ds-id (vec (ds/q '[:find ?id
                                          :where
                                          [?id :block/included true]]
                                        @conn))]
  (let [content (first (first (vec (ds/q '[:find ?content
                                           :where
                                           [?included-block-ds-id :block/content ?content]]
                                         @conn))))]
    (ds/transact! conn [[:db/add (first included-block-ds-id)
                         :block/hiccup (block-content->hiccup
                                        conn
                                        content)]])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your code is correct, yet not optimal performance-wise. You can use single query to retrieve all id-content pairs. Then build a single transaction out of them using `for`. Then transact it all at once.

```
(let [db @conn
      id+content (ds/q '[:find ?id ?content
                         :where [?id :block/included true]
                                [?id :block/content ?content]]
                   db)
      tx (for [[id content] id+content]
           [:db/add id :block/hiccup (block-content->hiccup db content)])]
  (ds/transact! conn tx))
```

Notice that it’s in general a good idea to take an immutable value of your database at some point in time and then do all calculations based on it (e.g. in passing to `block-content->hiccup` function). Only pass conn when you need function to alter the db.

You don’t need it in this case, but in general, if you only need to look up attributes on a single entity, it’s much more efficient to use `ds/entity` instead of query:

```
(:block/content (d/entity db id))
```

Comment: This makes more sense, but I'm still getting a StackOverflowError whenever I try to query the db for the newly created `:block/hiccup` for any of the entities. Here's the stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/wEnmvW6e
BTW, this same error occurs when using `(:block/hiccup (ds/entity db id))`.

Comment: what does (block-content->hiccup db content) return? from stacktrace it seems that you put the database inside a database somehow

Comment: Oh my goodness... Looks like I was calling (block-content->hiccup conn content) instead of (block-content->hiccup content conn). I guess my brain saw that both started with "con" and went "yeah, that con thing, put that here". For the moment I just had the function as an identity function for whatever content was passed in. But since I accidentally reversed the arguments, the "content" was the entire database. ‍♂️ write your :pre conditions, folks